# Toggle categories in a table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create a page that shows a table that contains products and I would like for the user to be able to toggle the categories. For example, if there are categories jeans, shirts and jackets, I would like a set of checkboxes that would toggle between showing the three categories of products. The problem is that I am unsure of how to approach this problem. I am not sure how to allow the user to relay the information to the controller without changing every users toggled categories. I also don't know how to get around the fact that refreshing the page to refresh the table would simply reset all of the categories.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way,

- based upon event click of checkbox fire up ajax request on `get req/param_catagory`
- get and assign data and load it over data table
- you can use jquery data table plugins for that
- There are few easy jquery plugins for that example: [jquery data table](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables)

Hope this will help.